# Как асинхронно найти и вернуть элемент объекта класса содержащий свойство с максимальным значением? .NET

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Есть класс модели Order:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int Quantity { get; set; } 

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Есть такой метод:

```
public  Task<Order> GetOrder()
{
    var orders=_dataManager.Orders.GetOrders();
    //return orders.Aggregate((x,y)=>x.Price>y.Price?x:y);
}
```

Необходимо найти заказ с самой большой суммой и вернуть это дело асинхронно. Как быть?

Comment: что такое `_dataManager`? Что такое `_dataManager.Orders`?

Comment: `return orders.MaxBy(x=>x.Price);`, зачем в данном коде асинхронность, я не знаю...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если есть только синхронный источник данных и решать в лоб, то как-то так

```
public Task<Order> GetMaxPriceOrder()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var orders = _dataManager.Orders.GetOrders();
        return orders.OrderByDescending(order => order.Price).First(); // или FirstOrDefault
    });
}
```

Для .NET 6+

```
public Task<Order> GetMaxPriceOrder()
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var orders = _dataManager.Orders.GetOrders();
        return orders.MaxBy(order => order.Price);
    });
}
```

Comment: вот и я думал так, но как то слишком просто и очевидно как будто, но спасибо за совет)

Comment: Есть же `return Task.FromResult(order);`

Comment: @tym32167 а куда это здесь прикрутить? Я исхожу из того что у автора тормозит код, типа обработка долгая и ему асинхронщина нужна, а не то что он реализует какой-то интерфейс. Типа просит асинхронно - я сделяль. Спросил бы как сделать синхронно, но завернуть результат в таск, я бы сделал по-другому.

Comment: @r0ge так что, не работает? Я не понял ваш комментарий.

Comment: все работает, я имел в виду, думал есть способ "научней"

Comment: а, ну я подумал про интерфейс, так как если надо именно искать асинхронно, то это проблема дата менеджера, а не его клиентов. Но и так сойдет )

Comment: @r0ge Добавил ещё один вариант решения.

Comment: Если судить по следующему вопросу автора, то у него идет работа с EF, который имеет асинхронный `.ToListAsync()` и др., что позволяет написать к примеру так: `await db.Orders.MaxBy(x=>x.Price).ToListAsync();` Правда что такое `_dataManager`, это прям вопрос хороший... Но думаю стоит упомянуть и этот вариант в ответе тоже.